# CSS Counter is giving wrong numbering in Chrome with slidetoggle

Tags: css, google-chrome, html-lists, slidetoggle, css-counter

Description:- Counter is incrementing contentiously on slide toggle. it's giving contentious number to the li outside ol. issue is coming in chrome and it's working fine in Mozilla.  so what's the solution for this?
 I have attached  output file at bottom.

```
<ol class="nav">
    <li>
        <a href="#">Parent-1</a>
        <ol class="nav">
            <li>child1</li>
            <li>child2</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">parent-2</a>
     <ol class="nav">
            <li>
            <a href="#">child-1</a>
            <ol class="nav">
              <li><a href="#">inner-most-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">innner-most-2</a></li>
            </ol>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">child-2</a></li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">parent-3</a></li>
</ol>
```

> Jquery

```
$(function() {
    $(".nav ol").hide();
        $(".nav > li > a").click(function(e) {
            $(this).siblings("ol").slideToggle();
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
```

> CSS:-

```
  ol{
       counter-reset: section;
       list-style-type: none;
        }
     ol li{
       counter-increment: section;
        }
     ol li:before {

     content: counters(section,".") " ";
      }
```

[OTPUT looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PApUD.png)
[Output -2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnLUc.png)

JS_Fiddle:-
https://jsfiddle.net/tushar115/f6zvu8w5/10/

Answer (score 0):

This is an bug in Chrome: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=822260 I'm thinking the only solution will be for Google to fix this. Otherwise someone would have to recreate the entire functionality of numbered lists.